# Extract several words that start with specific char EXCEL

Tags: excel

I have this formula to extract a specific word that starts with a given char “@”. It is working fine, however, there are more words starting with the same, it will only extract the first word.

How to make it extract all?

```
=TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(B2,FIND("@",B2),LEN(B2))," ",REPT(" ",100)),100))
```

Sample below:

```
Seq Desc                                extracted
1   text @word                          @word
2   text @word_one and @word_two        @word_one
```

Comment: Try this answer:
[Regex in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops)

Comment: What version of Excel?

Comment: And do you want the results in a single cell, with some kind of delimiter?  Or in multiple cells?

Comment: Excel 2013. I am fine with either one cell or separate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this formula. it is a slight modification of your formula. What it does is, it searches for the first @ sign than replaces it with ~~ and extracts contained word. then it searches for second @ sign and does the same.

```
=CONCATENATE(TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(B3,FIND("~~",SUBSTITUTE(B3,"@","~~",1)),LEN(B3))," ",REPT(" ",100),1),100)),",",TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(B3,FIND("~~",SUBSTITUTE(B3,"@","~~",2)),LEN(B3))," ",REPT(" ",100),1),100)))
```

[image]

If you would like to add third @ word to extract, just add another instance of CONCATENATE, and replace this `IFERROR(TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(B4,FIND("~~",SUBSTITUTE(B4,"@","~~",2(for third word replace value 2 with 3)),LEN(B4))` part of the formula with 3rd occurrence. so for extracting 3 values, please use this formula. (I added IFERROR part just in case word @ is not found)

```
=CONCATENATE(IFERROR(TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(B4,FIND("~~",SUBSTITUTE(B4,"@","~~",1)),LEN(B4))," ",REPT(" ",100),1),100)),""),",",IFERROR(TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(B4,FIND("~~",SUBSTITUTE(B4,"@","~~",2)),LEN(B4))," ",REPT(" ",100),1),100)),""),",",IFERROR(TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(B4,FIND("~~",SUBSTITUTE(B4,"@","~~",3)),LEN(B4))," ",REPT(" ",100),1),100)),""))
```

[image]