# Get several tags from excel cell

Tags: excel, find

In a single cell I have the text of the form:

> text **#tag1** another text, text **#anothertag**, etc.

I need to pull out all the tags in the next cell. The tag may have a different number of characters. We assume that any tag ends with a space at the end, i.e.

> **#tag1**, then the text

can be pulled out with a comma. If you can also trim the characters - would be great.

I can find one, but not all:

```
= MID (A2; SEARCH ("#"; A2) + 1; SEARCH (""; A2; SEARCH ("#"; A2) +1) - SEARCH ("" ; A2) - 1)
```

Any ideas ? No macros or external solutions, pure excel needed.

Comment: Found another solution, but with in advance defined number of tags: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46872736/extract-several-words-that-start-with-specific-char-excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Requires Excel for Office 365, Excel for Office 365 for Mac, Excel 2019

Following array formula will return the required result assuming your source string is in cell `A2`.

`=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(LEFT(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(" "&A2," ",REPT(" ",99)),ROW($A$1:$A$99)*99,99)))="#",TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(" "&A2," ",REPT(" ",99)),ROW($A$1:$A$99)*99,99)),""))`

Array formula shall be committed by <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

**Note:** Argument separator in my formula is "," whereas OP is using ";".

---

**Edit:**

---

> For Excel 2016 and older versions

Following longer route can be implemented which will first extract results to individual cells.In cell `C2` following formula shall be inserted.

`=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A2," ",REPT(" ",99))," #","|",COLUMNS($C$1:C1)),FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A2," ",REPT(" ",99))," #","|",COLUMNS($C$1:C1)),1)+1,99))`

Should be copied down and right as much as needed.

In column B then a `CONCATENATE` approach can be implemented as below (example for 10 cells).

`=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(CONCATENATE(C2," ",D2," ",E2," ",F2," ",G2," ",H2," ",I2," ",J2," ",K2))," ",", ")`

To be copied down.

Comment: tried to replace textjoin with concatenate (just to see the result) and the formula gave me back the first tag only

Comment: @jagger that is the issue with `CONCATENATE`. The alternative approach would be to extract individual entries and then `CONCATENATE` them to a single cell. See the edit for alternative approach.