# Removing all words that start with same characters in a cell in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I had some issues downloading my data from a server. I have many genes and their expression values merged into one cell [rather than split into multiple columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/928FK.png). Some cells have around 30 or so genes and their expression values. I can recover the expression values on the server if I can simply get the gene names out. All the genes start with 'Bn' so I tried this below to remove all words starting in a certain way, but it only works for around 2-3 words starting a certain way:

[Extract several words that start with specific char EXCEL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46872736/extract-several-words-that-start-with-specific-char-excel)

Does anyone know how I can extract all words starting with a certain character so that I can get a list of gene names? Thanks for any help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data sits in `A1` and one has `TEXTJOIN`, then try:

```
=TEXTJOIN("; ",1,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,";"," ")," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[starts-with(.,'Bn')]"))
```

Confirm through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

---

*Data used:*

```
BnaC01g15960D; --; Protein of unknown function6.00Nan2.680.54 3.392.689.392.703.351.26 2.500.596.888.013.69 BnaC02g00590D; --; AT5G0997618.006.831.704.594.934.648.964.034.161.964.701.7611.7710.639.08 BnaA05920890D; CYP707A4; cytochrome P450
```

Comment: How did u get that string? You probably weren't typing it out. :)

Comment: Thank you. I thought you have some miraculous site which can read from pictures or something like that.

Comment: If you want, you can add `=INDEX(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A$1,";"," ")," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[starts-with(.,'Bn')]"),ROW(A2))` for a version without `TEXTJOIN`, which works from EXCEL 2013 on. Just pull down.

Comment: Yes, I just assumed other data below the sample data. Btw, one needs `ROW(A1)` =) @OverflowStacker

Comment: Thank you, i will try that out. :) I guess it will be helpful on many occasions here on SO.

Comment: Whoops, i copied the formula from second row. :)